# Remove Duplicates on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to remove duplicates on robomongo, my version 3.0.12 so I cant use DropDups,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("id"),
    "Name" : "No One",
    "SituationDate" : "18-03-2017",
    "Situation" : "ACTIVE",
    "Region" : "13 REGION",
    "RegisterNumber" : "7649",
    "Version" : "20170517"
}
```

The RegisterNumber should be unique so I would like to remove as duplicates by the RegisterNumber.

EDIT :I just discovered that people from different regions can have the same registerNumber... How can I remove only those who have both RegisterNumber and Region the same

Solution:
Here is the solution given by @Neil Lunn with small modifications, I tested  it in a collection called `TEST` and it worked:

```
var bulk = db.getCollection('TEST').initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;

db.getCollection('TEST').aggregate([
  // Group on unique value storing _id values to array and count 
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { RegisterNumber: "$RegisterNumber", Region: "$Region" },
    "ids": { "$push": "$_id" },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }      
  }},
  // Only return things that matched more than once. i.e a duplicate
  { "$match": { "count": { "$gt": 1 } } }
]).forEach(function(doc) {
  var keep = doc.ids.shift();     // takes the first _id from the array

  bulk.find({ "_id": { "$in": doc.ids }}).remove(); // remove all remaining _id matches
  count++;

  if ( count % 500 == 0 ) {  // only actually write per 500 operations
      bulk.execute();
      bulk = db.getCollection('TEST').initializeOrderedBulkOp();  // re-init after execute
  }
});

// Clear any queued operations
if ( count % 500 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are prepared to simply discard all other duplicates then you basically want to [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) in order to collect the documents with the same `RegisterNumber` value and remove all other documents other than the first match.

MongoDB 3.0.x lacks some of the modern helpers but the basics that [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) returns a cursor for process large result sets and the presence of ["bulk operations"](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/Bulk/) for write performance still exists:

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;

db.collection.aggregate([
  // Group on unique value storing _id values to array and count 
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$RegisterNumber",
    "ids": { "$push": "$_id" },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }      
  }},
  // Only return things that matched more than once. i.e a duplicate
  { "$match": { "count": { "$gt": 1 } } }
]).forEach(function(doc) {
  var keep = doc.ids.shift();     // takes the first _id from the array

  bulk.find({ "_id": { "$in": doc.ids }}).remove(); // remove all remaining _id matches
  count++;

  if ( count % 500 == 0 ) {  // only actually write per 500 operations
      bulk.execute();
      bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();  // re-init after execute
  }
});

// Clear any queued operations
if ( count % 500 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

In more modern releases ( 3.2 and above ) it is preferred to use [`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) instead. Note that this is a 'client library' thing, as the same "bulk" methods shown above are actually called "under the hood":

```js
var ops = [];

db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$RegisterNumber",
    "ids": { "$push": "$id" },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }      
  }},
  { "$match": { "count": { "$gt": 1 } } }
]).forEach( doc => {

  var keep = doc.ids.shift();

  ops = [
    ...ops,
    {
      "deleteMany": { "filter": { "_id": { "$in": doc.ids } } }
    }
  ];

  if (ops.length >= 500) {
    db.collection.bulkWrite(ops);
    ops = [];
  }
});

if (ops.length > 0)
  db.collection.bulkWrite(ops);
```

So [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pulls everything together via the `$RegisterNumber` value and collects the matching document `_id` values to an array. You keep the count of how many times this happens using [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/).

Then filter out any documents that only had a count of `1` since those are clearly not duplicates.

Passing to the loop you remove the first occurance of `_id` in the collected list for the key with `.shift()`, leaving only other "duplicates" in the array.

These are passed to the "remove" operation with [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) as a "list" of documents to match and remove.

The process is generally the same if you need something more complex such as merging details from the other duplicate documents, it's just that you might need more care if doing something like converting the case of the "unique key" and therefore actually removing the duplicates first before writing changes to the document to be modified.

At any rate, the aggregation will highlight the documents that actually are "duplicates". The remaining processing logic is based on whatever you actually want to do with that information once you identify them.

Comment: I got this erro : ReferenceError: count is not defined

Comment: @kadzu  My bad. Forgot to declare the variable at the start of the listing. And please remember to strip the comments when pasting into the shell as well. They are just there for reference,

Comment: I just discovered that people from different regions can have the same registerNumber... How can I remove only those who have both RegisterNumber and Region the same?

Comment: It was not working but i found the problem , you forgot the underline before the ID, its `"ids": { "$push": "$_id" }` not `"ids": { "$push": "$id" },` in the `aggregate function`

Comment: I already placed the solution in my question. Fixed the erro, modified to only remove when both RegisterNumber and Region are the same. Thanks.

Comment: Btw, How long would it take to do this in a collection with 6.4 million documents like this? And during the execution would it stop me from using the entire database or only this collection?